# Filter .bib file for items that are actually used with \cite?

Tags: bibtex, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split all BibTeX referenced entries from a big BibTeX database to a copy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417/how-to-split-all-bibtex-referenced-entries-from-a-big-bibtex-database-to-a-copy)

I have one big `foo.bib` file that contains all my references. Every one of my different LaTeX documents uses this with `\bibliography{foo}` and cites only a subset of the contained references.

Is there a good script that takes one of my LaTeX documents (including everything it includes using `\input`) and extracts all the items in `foo.bib` that are cited?

In other words, I'd like to filter the big `foo.bib` file using a LaTeX document so that only the cited bibliography items survive.

Comment: Check out this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417/how-to-split-all-bibtex-referenced-entries-from-a-big-bibtex-database-to-a-copy

Comment: Definitely looks like a duplicate to me

Answer (score 4):

I think there are some perl scripts doing that.

But I use [RefTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) which offers a function `reftex-create-bibtex-file` that does just that.

Answer (score 1):

The `bibkey` command from [pybib](http://www.petercorke.com/pybib.html) can do this (amongst other tools)