# Using bibtool with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtool

I'm trying to use [bibtool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/) to extract bibliography information from an aux file. I'm using this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
@Book{dickens,
    author={Charles Dickens},
    title={A Tale of Two Cities},
    year=1859,
    publisher={Chapman and Hall}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}

\begin{document}
\cite{dickens}

\end{document}
```

When I run:

```
bibtool -x test.aux -o refs.bib
```

I get the following errors:

```
*** BibTool WARNING:  (line 2 in ./test-blx.bib): 23 non-space characters ignored.

*** BibTool WARNING:  (line 9 in ./test-blx.bib): 168 non-space characters ignored.

@Control{biblatex-control,
_^
*** BibTool ERROR:  (line 9 in ./test-blx.bib): Unknown entry type

*** BibTool WARNING: Skiping to next '@'

*** BibTool WARNING:  (line 5 in ./foo.bib): 96 non-space characters ignored.
```

My `test.aux` is as follows:

```
\relax 
\bibstyle{biblatex}
\bibdata{test-blx,foo}
\citation{biblatex-control}
\citation{dickens}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\abx@aux@page{1}{1}
```

I presume this problem is because this tool has been written for bibtex rather than biblatex. Is there a way to use this tool to extract the information, or is there a way to extract the bibliography information I need?

Comment: In case you are using `biber` to generate the bibliography, you might want to checkout the `--output-format=bibtex` commandline option as described in its [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer to this. Change `\bibstyle` to `plain` in your `.aux` file, and delete the `\citation{biblatex-control}` line. Also delete `test-blx.bib` from the `\bibdata` line.  `bibtool` should now be able to read your bibliography as per usual.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this does not directly address your question but as you are already using `biblatex`, `biber` might be an alternative to `bibtool` as outlined by this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145168/84655

If `test.tex` is your latex document, just run

```
biber test --output_format bibtex
```

and you get a file called `test_biber.bib` with the entries referenced in `test.tex`.

Comment: This is the much easier solution

Comment: I was just experimenting with this. This outputs a `.bib` file that renames the `year` field `date` and the `journal` field `journaltitle`...