# BibLaTeX: collective bibliography for independent documents

Tags: biblatex

I have a number of remote related documents, living in own directories, each with a BibLaTeX bibliography, all use common .bib files.
I want to generate a collective bibliography, i.e., a bibliography that includes all entries that are cited in one of the documents, without touching the original documents.

To archive this, several approaches has come in my mind, one uglier than the next:

- Generate a cover document that includes with some magic (e.g., `combine`, `docmute`) the documents ignoring their `\documentsclass` etc., and suppressing with more magic (`collect`, `comment`) everything but the bibliography.
- Use a shell script with `grep` and `awk` to find all kinds of cite-commands, construct a file with corresponding `\nocite` commands, that can be used to generate the bibliography.
- Use a XML parser to combine all .bcf files to a single one.

Before I start to implement one of these approaches, I want to ask the community: Do exist standard solutions for this problem? If not, are there other ideas?

Comment: You can use `biber --output-format=bibtex test.bcf`  to get the bib entries for the document `test` in `test-biber.bib`. You then only need a small document which uses all this bib's along with a nocite{*} to get a complete bibliography.

Comment: And if you have several documents, you could use `bibtool` to merge the `bib` files into one such file. (bibtool can also do the extraction. But see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/using-bibtool-with-biblatex) )

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Your approach works. If you make an answer out of it, I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `biber --output-format=bibtex test.bcf` to store the bib entries for the document `test` in `test-biber.bib`.

Then you only need a small document which uses all this `*-biber.bib`'s along with a `\nocite{*}` to get a complete bibliography.