# Sync missing citation/ list missing citations in script

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to be able to sync missing citations from a master `.bib` file into the `.bib` file  actually used for the paper I am writing.

Most reference managers seem to only support exporting to one giant file. This is not acceptable for collaboratively producing a paper when  not everyone uses the same manager or has the same total citation library.

If there is an existing tool to do this or some more elegant solution to the problem, great.

If not, i'd like to just amend the latex build chain to 1) build doc 2) get a list of missing citations 3) sync citations 4) rebuild.

Short of scrapping standard out/error, is there a good way to do this ?

Comment: Do you know [`checkcites`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites)

Comment: Probably [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417/how-to-split-all-bibtex-referenced-entries-from-a-big-bibtex-database-to-a-cop) is relevant.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)