# Resorting the *.bib file as appeared in *.tex and rewriting to a new *bib file (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, external-files

I have quite a huge database of citations, but not all of them are included in the document. And of course they are not ordered by appearance in the text, because sometimes I have to go back to some earlier part and include more citations. In our work group it is common practice to share the citation libraries with each other, once the thesis is finished. Since the `bibtex` format is quite common amongst many scientific journals I would like to include the bibliography as a digital copy. Hence I need to resort the whole `*.bib` file and remove citations unnecessary.

As suggested I have looked on the several possibilities mentioned in [How to split all BibTeX referenced entries from a big BibTeX database to a copy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417/how-to-split-all-bibtex-referenced-entries-from-a-big-bibtex-database-to-a-copy)

Unfortunately those work only for the bibtex case.

I suppose it does have to do something with how the literature is cited:

Bibtex:

```
\citation{Schroedinger1926}
```

Biblatex:

```
\abx@aux@cite{Schroedinger1926}
```

That way neither [BibTool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool) nor [Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/index.php) do the job.
I am currently trying the `bibtex2html` approach, but that does not compile.

One thing that I probably should mention is that I am using biber as a backend.

So, the basic question is how can I get the same result with the above combination for biber+biblatex.

I could change those commands by hand, but I really do not want to mess around with automatically written files.
( I could do it with `grep` and `sed` but I would rather save the pain.)

Comment: OK, done, but doesn't the JabRef approach work? (You'll need to be using the BibTeX back end rather than Biber.)

Comment: @JosephWright Am I able to switch between those, without messing things up?

Comment: [**`checkcites`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/checkcites) may be a good starting point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `biber` dev version 1.8 from SourceForge. This now allows output to BibTeX format instead of `.bbl` (this is in addition to the already available "tool mode" which transforms entire data sources). So, you can do this:

```
pdflatex file
biber --output_format=bibtex file
```

and instead of a `.bbl`, you will get `file_biber.bib` which contains only the cited entries, in citation order. You can use the various `--output_*` options to control the indentation, casing, crossref resolution etc. of the output and you are free to use any other biber options to re-encode or transform the data before output. You will need to be using at least biblatex 2.7 to use biber 1.7+.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`bibtex2html`](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/). In particular, you can use `aux2bib` command-line tool as explained in the [documentation](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/doc/manual.pdf).

Another option is to use [`BibTool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/) as explained in the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424/7269) linked by Jagath AR.