# biblatex biber to \bibitem

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I am a LaTeX really entusiastic newbie. Thus I am writing all my reports and articles using this wonderful tool. Unfortunately the editors of scientific review do not all have the same entusiasm concerning LaTeX. I plan to submit my future paper in the ICES Journal of Science which (fortunately or not) has a kind of LaTeX template available online (http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/icesjms/ices.zip) and guidelines available here (http://www.oxfordjournals.org/for_authors/latex.html).

My main problem is concerning bibliography. In all my writing I use `biblatex` with in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
firstinits=true,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=7,
backend=biber]{biblatex}.
```

In the text I call citation using `\autocite`, `\textcite`, `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`.

As requested by the journal I tried to convert my bibliography into a `\bibitem` list. I went to check the `.bbl` file as advised online but the structure seemed really complicated and nowhere `\bibitem` was mentionned. I found online some method that I managed to make work in my case by creating a dummy `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
sdryfj
\bibliography{BIB.testbib.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\cite{NumR}
\end{document}
```

I run some compilation and got a `.bbl` file with `\bibitem`s list. I thought I was seeing the end of it and paste this list in `thebibliography` environment at the end of my document.

Unfortunately all my citations references (`\autocite` etc..) seems to not be compatible with this different way of bibliography input. In addition, all the references are printed cited or not....

I was wondering if there is a way to reach the same results directly from `biber biblatex` so I would not have to modify my document too much...

Thank you for your help,

Xochitl C.

PS: I also tried to redefine commands like this but it did not work:

```
\renewcommand{\autocite}{\cite}

\renewcommand{\citeauthor}{\cite}

\renewcommand{\citeyear}{\cite}

\renewcommand{\textcite}{\cite}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Does [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) help you? Unfortunately, the answer there is: It is quite complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the thread. §Unfortunately it doesn't really help as my journal specify it wants the references with    `\bibitem` structure and I dont think that's what the other code does. I did manage to convert my `biblatex` into `bibitem` but cannot deal with the reference in the text.... Any clue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found a somewhat more or less complex workaround, which I hope helps you at least a little bit. Consider this MWE, I will call `main.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{testA,
author = {A. Uthor},
title = {A title},
year = {2014},
publisher = {A Company}
}
@BOOK{testB,
author = {B. Uthor},
title = {B title},
year = {2014},
publisher = {B Company}
}
@BOOK{testC,
author = {C. Uthor},
title = {C title},
year = {2014},
publisher = {C Company}
}
@BOOK{testD,
author = {D. Uthor},
title = {D title},
year = {2014},
publisher = {D Company}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            firstinits=true,
            uniquename=false,
            uniquelist=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=7,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Initial order in the bib file was A, B, C and D.

We will cite D\cite{testD} first, then A\cite{testA} and B\cite{testB} and C not at all.

You can refer to A\cite{testA} again.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This will result in

[image: output of main.tex]

I will assume your document will compile without error, so you can run the following command:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex main[.bcf]
```

This will create a file `main_biber.bib` in which all references are sorted according to the biblatex style you chose. Compare [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124667/resorting-the-bib-file-as-appeared-in-tex-and-rewriting-to-a-new-bib-file).

Then create the following `dummy.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{main_biber.bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

Note: `main_biber.bib` was created automagically. Use `unsrt` to keep the order created by biber. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144639/how-do-i-order-citations-by-appearance-using-bibtex).

Run the following commands:
    pdflatex dummy; bibtex dummy

Please see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124874/converting-to-bibitem-in-latex).

This will create a file `dummy.bbl` in the bibitem format. Clean your initial `main.tex` of all biblatex stuff and append `dummy.bbl`. For convenience this will be called `newmain.tex` and should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Initial order in the bib file was A, B, C and D.

We will cite D\cite{testD} first, then A\cite{testA} and B\cite{testB} and C not at all.

You can refer to A\cite{testA} again.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{testD}
D.~Uthor.
\newblock {\em D title}.
\newblock D Company, 2014.

\bibitem{testA}
A.~Uthor.
\newblock {\em A title}.
\newblock A Company, 2014.

\bibitem{testB}
B.~Uthor.
\newblock {\em B title}.
\newblock B Company, 2014.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

It will then change to a numerical citation order, but I think that will be dealt with by the journal editors. Run pdflatex (at least twice) and you will obtain:

[image: output of newmain.tex]

Your document should then be ready for submission.

Comment: I just saw, that you still have to (re)define any `biblatex` citations you use to match `\cite`. Of course most/all of the perks of biblatex are removed by all of this.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the help. 2 questions: 
What does mean : `biber --output_format=bibtex main[.bcf]`? I think it's some code used while using Linux but I am using Windows and do not really understand what to do. 
Is there a way to redefine `biblatex` citations to match `\cite` automatically without having to go trought the text? I try `renewcommand` but it was giving me errors. Thanks!

Comment: What tools do you use in windows? They probably come with a build in terminal editor. You may be able to run biber from the commandline, which you can get with `cmd` (search in startmenu). 2) Because you have to remove all biblatex stuff, the `\*cite` commands are not available, you have to define them with `\newcommand{\autocite}[1]{\cite{#1}}` of course any biblatex functionality is lost therefore.

Comment: Excellent post, thanks Martin. At the time of my comment`\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` did not compile but `\addbibresource{jobname.bib}` did. That is, second backslash removed. Presumably this is due to a change in Biblatex processing. As a separate note: the environment beginning `\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}` can be placed after `\end{document}` without problems. Some of us will prefer to structure our document that way.

Comment: @JohnBentley The command `\jobname` is a tex primitive (comp. [here](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#jobname-rp)) and should simply use the name of your name file. You might just have forgotten the slash in the `filecontents` command. They do of course need to match. Also note that I am not using [`filecontents`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents), only the built-in functionality. Therefore the environment has to go in the preamble. I personally only use this command for MWEs to make it more convenient to copy and try.

Comment: Using this solution with the latest version (2.14) of Biber produces a `main_biber.bib` file with `DATE` fields replacing the `YEAR` fields. So one has to do a search&replace before proceeding, otherwise BibTeX will show warnings about the absence of `YEAR` fields.

Answer (score 8):

In support of the accepted answer, I just wanted to add a test file for reference.

Basically, a bibliography can be compiled either with "plain" `bibtex`, or with `biblatex` with `bibtex` backend, or with `biblatex` with `biber` backend. In all three cases a `.bbl` file is produced - but in all three cases the format of the `.bbl` file is different!

`\bibitem` occurs in the `.bbl` file only when "plain" `bibtex` is used. (`biblatex` uses `\entry`, `\strng`, `\field` etc)

In this particular test file, there is no difference in (pdf) output between backends when `biblatex` is used - but there is a slight difference (*e.g. quotation marks and capitalization in title, the "In:" ...*) between the "plain" `bibtex` (left) and `biblatex` outputs (right, click for full res):

[image: bibtest_01_plainbibtex]
[image: bibtext_02_biblatex]

The test file is this, let's call it `bibtest.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{smith1,
  author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
  title={The book with a very very very very very long title},
  year={2006},
  location={New York},
  publisher={Publisher},
}

@article{audactor2005pflanzen,
  title = {Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik},
  author = {Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor},
  journal = {Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/2005/sonobotanik.html}},
  year = {2005}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% btype: 1: bibtex ; 2: biblatex+bibtex ; 3: biblatex+biber
\ifx\btype\undefined %
  \def\btype{1} %
\fi
\ifnum\btype=2 %
  \usepackage[url=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} %
  \bibliography{\jobname} %
\fi
\ifnum\btype=3 %
  \usepackage[url=true,backend=biber]{biblatex} %
  \bibliography{\jobname} %
\fi

\begin{document}

Just testing the bibliography: the book \cite{smith1}, and the article \cite{audactor2005pflanzen}.

\ifnum\btype=1 %
  \bibliographystyle{plain}         % Style BST file
  \bibliography{\jobname}           % Bibliography file ('*.bib' )
\else % \btype=2 or 3
  %\bibliography{\jobname}           % for biblatex, only in preamble!
  \printbibliography %
\fi

\end{document}

% clean: rm $(ls --hide=*.tex)
```

Here are the steps and results of the compilation:

#### 1. plain `bibtex`

```bash
# \btype=1
pdflatex bibtest.tex  # creates: .aux, .bib, .log, .out, .pdf
bibtex bibtest        # creates: .bbl, .blg
pdflatex bibtest.tex
pdflatex bibtest.tex
```

The produced `bibtest.bbl` file is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{audactor2005pflanzen}
Prof. Dr.~Hortensia Audactor.
\newblock Wie pflanzen hören... die geheimnisse der sonobotanik.
\newblock {\em Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/2005/sonobotanik.html}},
  2005.

\bibitem{smith1}
John Smith and Mike Someone.
\newblock {\em The book with a very very very very very long title}.
\newblock Publisher, 2006.

\end{thebibliography}
```

#### 2. `biblatex` and backend `bibtex`

```bash
pdflatex "\def\btype{2}\input{bibtest.tex}" # creates: .aux, .bib, -blx.bib, .log, .out, .pdf, .run.xml
bibtex bibtest                              # creates: .bbl, .blg
pdflatex "\def\btype{2}\input{bibtest.tex}" # biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'. Use backend=biber.
```

The produced `bibtest.bbl` file is:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex version 1.7 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated as
% required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup

\entry{audactor2005pflanzen}{article}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Audactor}{A.}%
     {Prof. Dr.~Hortensia}{P.~D.~H.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{APDH1}
  \strng{fullhash}{APDH1}
  \field{sortinit}{A}
  \field{title}{Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik}
  \field{journaltitle}{Draft:
  \url{http://www.inventionen.de/2005/sonobotanik.html}}
  \field{year}{2005}
\endentry

\entry{smith1}{book}{}
  \name{author}{2}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Smith}{S.}%
     {John}{J.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
    {{}%
     {Someone}{S.}%
     {Mike}{M.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {Publisher}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{SJSM1}
  \strng{fullhash}{SJSM1}
  \field{sortinit}{S}
  \field{title}{The book with a very very very very very long title}
  \list{location}{1}{%
    {New York}%
  }
  \field{year}{2006}
\endentry

\lossort
\endlossort

\endinput
```

#### 2. `biblatex` and backend `biber`

```bash
pdflatex "\def\btype{3}\input{bibtest.tex}" # creates: .aux, .bcf, .bib, .log, .out, .pdf, .run.xml
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 biber bibtest              # creates: .bbl, .blg
pdflatex "\def\btype{3}\input{bibtest.tex}"
```

The produced `bibtest.bbl` file is:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex version 1.7 $
% $ biber version 0.9.9 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber or bibtex as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \entry{audactor2005pflanzen}{article}{}
    \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
      {{hash=1d15dc798dec1fd384ab9a796ebab9f5}{Audactor}{A\bibinitperiod}{Prof.\bibnamedelimi Dr.\bibnamedelimi Hortensia}{P\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim D\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim H\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
    }
    \name{author}{1}{}{%
      {{hash=1d15dc798dec1fd384ab9a796ebab9f5}{Audactor}{A\bibinitperiod}{Prof.\bibnamedelimi Dr.\bibnamedelimi Hortensia}{P\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim D\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim H\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
    }
    \strng{namehash}{1d15dc798dec1fd384ab9a796ebab9f5}
    \strng{fullhash}{1d15dc798dec1fd384ab9a796ebab9f5}
    \field{sortinit}{A}
    \field{journaltitle}{Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/2005/sonobotanik.html}}
    \field{title}{Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik}
    \field{year}{2005}
  \endentry

  \entry{smith1}{book}{}
    \name{labelname}{2}{}{%
      {{hash=5d0ddda3a367ceb26fbaeca02e391c22}{Smith}{S\bibinitperiod}{John}{J\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      {{hash=51e9bdc59ecfdbdb5cf9ee7ecd37d83f}{Someone}{S\bibinitperiod}{Mike}{M\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
    }
    \name{author}{2}{}{%
      {{hash=5d0ddda3a367ceb26fbaeca02e391c22}{Smith}{S\bibinitperiod}{John}{J\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      {{hash=51e9bdc59ecfdbdb5cf9ee7ecd37d83f}{Someone}{S\bibinitperiod}{Mike}{M\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
    }
    \list{location}{1}{%
      {New York}%
    }
    \list{publisher}{1}{%
      {Publisher}%
    }
    \strng{namehash}{bdb6caeb721d71d176dbc1db99a48c69}
    \strng{fullhash}{bdb6caeb721d71d176dbc1db99a48c69}
    \field{sortinit}{S}
    \field{title}{The book with a very very very very very long title}
    \field{year}{2006}
  \endentry

\endrefsection
\endinput
```