# BibLaTeX -> LaTeX source code

Tags: biblatex

When I run bibtex, I can extract the LaTeX code from the bbl file. Then, I can combine that directly into my LaTeX file so that the copyeditors, for instance, don't need to know anything about how I created my bibliography.

I'd like to do the same think with BibLaTeX, i.e., grab the LaTeX code that it produces and include that in my LaTeX file. Where is that code or how can I produce it?

Comment: Have a look at this: [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). There is also [biblatex biber to \bibitem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154215/35864) But then keep in mind that some publishers use really, really old and outdated systems, so you cannot even rely on `biblatex` being in their system.