# biblatex generated bibliography in thebibliography environment

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Some journals ask to put the references in `thebibliography` environment. It is easy to do this using `bibtex`. One just finds the `bbl` file and paste everything in there, to the main text.

However, I could not find a similar way to do same when bibliography is generated by `biblatex`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why, biblatex also produces a .bbl file.

Comment: @Bernard But not in a format you can just paste into a `thebibliography` environment!

Comment: @cfr: I didn't know (never had to use a `thebibliography` environment for years).

Comment: @Bernard I had a look ;). Then I searched one for `bibitem` and drew a blank. If it doesn't look like a duck and it doesn't 'cwac' like a duck, I figure the chances are that it probably isn't a duck. (Welsh ducks say 'cwac'.) I've actually never used a `thebibliography` environment except recently to teach a LaTeX workshop. I had to learn it for the first time.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154215/biblatex-biber-to-bibitem help?

Comment: @cfr: And Welsh rabbits? (or Welsh wabbits, as in *Life of Brian*).

Comment: @Bernard They're toast ;).

Comment: @cfr: Rarely :o)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get my answer from the link.

Comment: There is also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link. I think I've got my answer. Feel free to close the question. :)

Comment: Great, I just cast a vote vote. If you come across any problem with the solution you can of course update this question here with the specific problem and it will most probably be reopened.

Comment: @moewe That doesn't use `thebibliography`, does it? Is the requirement really just to have it all in one file?

Comment: @cfr It seems so, yes. Maybe then [biblatex biber to \bibitem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154215/35864) is slightly more relevant.

Comment: @moewe That's what I thought but the OP said it didn't help. So maybe the question is just not quite the right one!

Comment: @cfr Oh yes, I overlooked that one, but then the OP was fine with the question that is currently marked as a duplicate, so I don't really see a big problem here. Until the OP comes back and complains that something didn't quite work, that is.

Comment: @moewe Oh, certainly. I was just commenting for clarification really and in case anybody else turns up who really has *this* question!