# How to delete the unused Bibtex items in JabRef?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, jabref

I'm writing the notes and using the software--JabRef v2.10 for managing the references. However, after revising my notes several times, I find that there are some unused Bibtex items.

So how to delete those unused Bibtex items?

Comment: The whole point of a bibtex file is to maintain a database of publications that can dynamically add references to a paper etc if they are cited. If some entries are not being used in a particular paper that's fine. Maybe in the next paper they will be. (This said, in jabref you can just hit the delete key -- or selection "delete" from the edit menu -- to delete publication. In the paper, if you run bibtex/biblatex again any uncited articles will be removed.)

Comment: See also [Unused bibliography entries - how to check which entries were not used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43276/35864), [How to split all BibTeX referenced entries from a big BibTeX database to a copy?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417/35864), [Resorting the *.bib file as appeared in *.tex and rewriting to a new *bib file (biblatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124667/35864), [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864).

Comment: In [Creating .bib file containing only the cited references of a bigger .bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864) you even get a JabRef solution.