# Is there a way to generate a .bib file from LyX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, collaboration

I have a "master" .bib file which I used for adding all my references to papers in the .lyx file.

I want my collaborator to now make some edits and add some references, but I don't want to give him my whole .bib file because it has thousands of entres and my own personal notes as comments.

Is there a way for LyX to generate only the .bib entries necessary for this particular project, and then we can use that .bib file for the rest of our work on this paper?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417/35864

Comment: LyX does generate the `.aux` file, but it's hidden away in a temporary directory. Where depends on your operating system I think, but try going to Tool --> Preferences --> Paths in LyX, and find the path to "Temporary directory". There you'll probably find a subfolder which contains the `.tex` file generated by LyX, and the various temporary files generated during compilation. Try grabbing the `.aux` file from there, and use one of the methods in the questions moewe mentions.

Comment: Did the links and Torbjørn's comment help? Did you get anywhere? Or do you need more pointers? If that is the case it would help if you could edit your question and explain explicitly what you are having trouble with after reading the links and comments.

Comment: Is there any new development here? As the question stands now it is a duplicate of one of the linked questions and I will vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe: Thank you very much for all your help, and for not voting for closure yet. Please give me some time to try some of these things! I'm working a full-time job with such a hectic schedule, I get so little time to work on writing my book (which I'm using LyX for) ....