# Extracting all bibtex items with a value for a certain field

Tags: bibtex

I want to extract all bibtex items that have a value for the field checked. That is from a file containing the two entries below, I want the second one only. The exact value of the field does not matter.

```
@proceedings{HPSG2021,
 address = {Frankfurt/Main},
 booktitle = {{Proceedings of the 28th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar, Online (Frankfurt\slash Main)}},
 editor = {Müller, Stefan and Melnik, Nurit},
 publisher = {University Library},
 title = {{Proceedings of the 28th International Conference on Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar, Online (Frankfurt\slash Main)}},
 year = {2021}}


@incollection{Haider2000a,
 address = {Amsterdam},
 author = {Hubert Haider},
 booktitle = {The Derivation of {VO} and {OV}},
 checked = {stmue 2021},
 doi = {10.1075/la.31.03hai},
 editor = {Peter Svenonius},
 number = {31},
 pages = {45--67},
 publisher = {Benjamins},
 series = {Linguistik aktuell},
 title = {{OV} is More Basic than {VO}},
 year = {2000}}
```

Comment: Have you considered biblatex? Such things are much easier there.

Comment: I am using biblatex, but I want to produce a resource for other people and extract all bibtex items that have been verified. Once items are verified I use the field `checked` and add who did the checking. Now I want to extract all items with the field used. I guess grep magic may do this, but I cannot do this. I could do a Perl program, but ...

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366139/36296 (and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41821/36296 for more options, but I would use biblatex)

Comment: OK. This is how to get all cited items from a document. In order to apply this, I would have to know how to cite all items with the `checked` field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bibtool](http://gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/) to filter the entries:

```bash
bibtool -r biblatex -- select{"checked"} references.bib
```

Will return only those entries in `references.bib`, where a key matches `checked`:

```
@InCollection{    haider2000a,
  address   = {Amsterdam},
  author    = {Hubert Haider},
  booktitle = {The Derivation of {VO} and {OV}},
  checked   = {stmue 2021},
  doi       = {10.1075/la.31.03hai},
  editor    = {Peter Svenonius},
  number    = {31},
  pages     = {45--67},
  publisher = {Benjamins},
  series    = {Linguistik aktuell},
  title     = {{OV} is More Basic than {VO}},
  year      = {2000}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem of bibtool is that it does not know collection as a type. Can I do something about this?

Comment: A further problem is that features are inherited from other items. So if I have book and incollection and the book has a checked value, all items crossreferencing this item inherit the checked feature. This is intended in normal cases, I guess, but it is not in my case.

Comment: For the first thing: use the option `-r biblatex` to more types. For the second one: you can probably switch crossref off with `expand.crossref = off` *(untested)*. You might want to peek in the [manual](http://gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/bibtool.pdf) for the rather complex configuration options...